# Delete all tiff metadata

Tags: metadata, geotiff-tiff

It seems I have a similar problem to [GeoTIFF world file ignored by QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125069/geotiff-world-file-ignored-by-qgis)

QGIS doesn't import my ground-layer tiff-files correctly, because I have the geo data in an extra tfw-file.

Now I want to delete all gdal-metadata in a bunch of tiff files.

Is there a Linux command line tool for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With gdal_translate

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co PROFILE=BASELINE input_geotiff.tif output_clean.tif
```

http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html
http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html

Comment: And after running the above command, don't forget to delete the gdal_translate generated *.aux.xml file if you need to get rid of metainfo completely.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php) mogrify:

```
mogrify -strip *.tiff
```

Comment: I got an error `mogrify: Unknown field with tag 42112 (0xa480) encountered. \`TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/896.
[n` is that bad? anyway, this didn't solve my problem

Comment: You can use `identify -verbose image.tif` to see if the metadata is gone. Apart from that there's [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to manipulate metadata, but i've never used it.