# Georeferenced image in ArcMap: replace the image file, keep the georeferencing information

Tags: arcmap, georeferencing, replace

I have georeferenced the image `myimage.tiff` in ArcMap 10.8. The file bundle of that georeferenced image then is:

```
myimage.tfwx
myimage.tiff
myimage.tiff.aux.xml
myimage.tiff.ovr
myimage.tiff.xml
```

In the meantime, I have produced a new version of `myimage.tiff` (with the same name) in another folder. I replaced the file in the list above by this new file by a simple copy-paste. I expected that I could keep the georeferencing information by this procedure as the georeferencing information is not stored in the file `myimage.tiff` itself. However, ArcMap still shows the older version. Is there a mistake in my understanding of the file bundle or in my proceeding?

Comment: Georeferencing *is* stored in GeoTIFF images.

Comment: Maybe try these tricks for removing the georeferencing information from your new version.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218342/delete-all-tiff-metadata

Comment: This is an expected behaviour:)